# Display Bitmap images in a GridView

Tags: android, xamarin, android-gridview, android-adapter, android-bitmap

In Xamarin, I have an `Activity` that has a `GridView` and a list of image web addresses. A list of `Bitmap` objects are retrieved and then displayed in the `GridView` from these web addresses.

Here is my `MainActivity` code:

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    GridView gridView;
    List<String> bitmapUris;
    List<Bitmap> gridViewItems;

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
        gridView = FindViewById<GridView>(Resource.Id.gridView);

        bitmapUris = new List<string> ();
        bitmapUris.Add ("http://images4.fanpop.com/image/photos/15000000/My-Sample-Pictures-lexi-and-sophie-15061826-1024-768.jpg");
        bitmapUris.Add ("http://www.cameraegg.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/AF-S-DX-NIKKOR-18-140mm-f-3.5-5.6G-ED-VR-sample-images-1.jpg");
        bitmapUris.Add ("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/5d/The_Samples-Outpost.jpg");
        bitmapUris.Add ("http://www.1800postcards.com/images/samples/sample_kits2.jpg");

        gridViewItems = GetBitmapImages (bitmapUris);
        gridView.Adapter = new GridViewAdapter (this, gridViewItems);
    }

    List<Bitmap> GetBitmapImages(List<String> bitmapUris)
    {
        List<Bitmap> images = new List<Bitmap> ();
        Bitmap image;
        foreach (var uri in bitmapUris) 
        {
            image = GetImageBitmapFromUri (uri);
            images.Add (image);
        }
        return images;
    }

    private Bitmap GetImageBitmapFromUri(string uri)
    {
        Bitmap imageBitmap = null;

        using (var webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            var imageBytes = webClient.DownloadData(uri);
            if (imageBytes != null && imageBytes.Length > 0)
            {
                imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
            }
        }

        return imageBitmap;
    }
}
```

Here is my `GridViewAdapter` code:

```
public class GridViewAdapter : BaseAdapter
{
    Activity context;
    List<Bitmap> gridViewtems;

    public GridViewAdapter (Activity context, List<Bitmap> gridViewtems)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.gridViewtems = gridViewtems;
    }

    public override int Count {
        get { return gridViewtems.Count; }
    }

    public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem (int position)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override long GetItemId (int position)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    public override View GetView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null)
            view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.GridViewItemWithImageAndText, null);
        view.FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.image).SetImageBitmap (gridViewtems[position]);
        view.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.text).Text = position.ToString();
        return view;

    }
}
```

Currently, when the application loads up, the screen goes blank until the `Bitmaps` are retrieved from the web addresses.

My question is this: How can I display the `Activity` with place holders for the `GridView` items, and when each `Bitmap` is retrieved, the relevant `GridView` item image is populated?
Is this done in the `MainActivity`, or in the `GridViewAdapter`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: use lazy loading http://stackoverflow.com/a/559781/964741

Answer (score 2):

Try to use Universal Image Loader for showing images from url to your GridView.

Refer this:
https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Comment: Thanks. How can I add the Universal Image Loader to my Xamarin project? I see that there are many .jar files in the download folder.

Comment: You can find download ZIP option at right hand side corner at last.When you download this you will find few files in src folder and universal-image-loader-1.9.2-SNAPSHOT-with-sources.jar in libs folder. You need to use that jar file

Comment: I have that file, where do I place it to use the class in Xamarin?

Comment: place that file in your libs folder

Comment: I do not currently have a libs folder, where should I create this?

Comment: Refere this: http://www.itexico.com/blog/bid/100447/Android-Wear-Developer-Preview-Using-Xamarin-Jar-Binding

Comment: Thanks. Can you please have a look at this link of mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24301216/add-a-jar-file-to-my-xamarin-project?